# Node JS callback executed without waiting

Tags: node.js, callback

I have the following function which performs a GET call. I want to wait for the response and then perform the next step. My code looks like this

```
getListOfChannels : function(token, callback){
  var Channels = [];
  var options = { method: 'GET',
  url: url,
  headers: 
  { 
    'x-api-key': token } };

  request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);

  var json = JSON.parse(body)
  var data = json.MemberEntitlement;
  for(var i=0 ; i < data.length ; i++){
    if(data[i].Entitled == false){
        Channels.push(data[i].ChannelNumber);

    }
  }
});
  callback(Channels[0]);
}
```

Also my callback function is just printing the value

```
simplePrint : function(arg){
  console.log(arg)
}
```

But still, the callback function does not wait for the full response and prints out undefined. 
What should i do. I can add implicit wait but that doesnt seem like a good practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are invoking **callback** after the **request** function invocation. It's not in **request**'s scope, but in **getListOfChannels** scope. Therefore, **callback** is running synchronously. Try replacing:

`});
  callback(Channels[0]);
}`

with

`callback(Channels[0]);
});
}`

Comment: I was suspecting this behavior. Does calling the callback function in the scope of request wait for the whole stream of response ?

Comment: Sometimes. It waits for the readable stream object to come back. If the body is short, the readable stream object will include the only chunk. If the body is long, it could return the stream (with one chunk) and then more chunks after that.